# Looking for XNA patterns

Tags: xna, c#, patterns

Hello mature game developers. Im just started with XNA, but i got solid expirence with C#.
I wonder is there any common code patterns for XNA games?

Like should i make classes wich handle draw and update separatly, like draw model and world  data model? Or should i try to put as much code as possible in Game1 ?

Im totaly lost in project structure building. Thx for any answers.

Comment: it depends on the complexity of your game. If you ar trying to implement the hangman, textual version, you could include everything in your game1 class. 
if your needs are more complex then you could need to work with Components, which has personal update and draw.

Comment: to fit better asking here you should add details at least on what your game idea is, bacause this question is too generic, imho

Comment: It will 2d turn based strategy/rpg in semi-random generated world. So i need a chain like "player click - game model make calculations - screen updated".

Comment: Here's a (my) [popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5459955/165500) on the subject.

Comment: @AndrewRussell thx. I just was think there is something like MVC/MVVM etc. designed specially for XNA games. But looks like im free to use my own abstraction models.

Comment: The best thing would be start building smaller games nad go from there.

Comment: @ashes999 i dont believe in such practice. While you make hello world you will only learn to make hello world. In small game i can put all my code in 3 files and etc.

Comment: @nuclearsweet A lot of game development is getting a "feel" for how much architecture you need. It's very easy to go overboard. If you start with something extremely simple, you can get an idea of how little architecture you can get away with. Generally: **less architecture == less code == easier to modify == better**. (Work *down* my list in my afforelinked "game architecture" answer, not up.)

Comment: (Also take a look at [this presentation](http://the-witness.net/news/2011/06/how-to-program-independent-games/) ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjDsP5n2kSM)) for some more relevant thoughts.)

Comment: @nuclearsweet drawing vs. update and data-driven architecture are present in simple games too.  My "hello world" is a roguelike. You can try that, or Tetris.

Comment: Personally i don't write more then a handfull of lines within Game1.cs. Often i build somekind of Engine class that i call from Game1.cs, this gives me much more overview. Let's say i create a Player class, in this class i also have a load/update/draw method i call from Engine. If my player class needs something like the GFX device i pass that on to update and then to player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC architecture doesn't work so great for games. Typically games use a very simple one-to-one OOP architecture where game objects typically have methods like `Update` and `Draw`.

In the cases where an MVC architecture would seem useful - often in networking scenarios - you usually just go the simple route with the OOP `Update`/`Draw` model, implemented in such a way that if `Draw` is never called, it doesn't matter.

(This can be tricky with "retained mode" APIs, but XNA is "immediate mode", so it's less of an issue.)

In game development, it's very unusual to be in a situation where you need to support multiple views on a model, where the views are substantially different enough that you need architectural support.

One place you often see an MVC-*like* architecture is in board- and card-games. These scenarios can often look very much like functional-programming. Where you have a (usually immutable) game-state and methods for advancing that state to generate a new one. The big reason for using an architecture like this is for AI.

(And *still*, in these cases, you can easily just implement `Draw` methods on your game state that don't care whether they get called or not.)

In all of these scenarios, there's not much built in to XNA to help you. You have to build everything yourself, starting from the given `Draw` and `Update` and other methods in `Game`. (There's `DrawableGameComponent`, but that gets you very little that you couldn't trivially do yourself, while limiting what you can do, so I generally recommend against using it.)

Finally, as I mentioned in comments, I've got a [very popular answer on game architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459955/165500) over on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks! For now i implement my game objects like in SO answer, but with only difference: i totaly separate logic and drawning. On update i calculate all i need and pass data to my DrawModel object. OnDraw call my DrawModel.Draw() method and draw what need. I made this to more easy change all graphics without affect any gameplay. Its just because i plan really big project, like dream game of my life, that can grow from tile game to modern graphic if i find some support and people will like it.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is not a meaningful decoupling unless you have multiple `DrawModel` types (at the same time). It will be far quicker to keep a simple architecture (ie: member `Draw` methods) and, when the time comes, to create a branch in version control (you are using that, right?) and do a "Find All References" to the `Draw` method and modify those methods to modernise the graphics. There is an *excellent* chance that any complicated architecture you create now will be "wrong" for advanced graphics in any case! So the less code you have to write and maintain now, the better.

Comment: Yeah, im using microsoft free TFS as team from one man :) Mby you right, need think more about that. I already face that i need so much enums to send into DrawModel different object states.